# If $X$ is discrete and $Z,W$ are discrete or continuous, is it always the case that $P(X=x\mid Z=z) \geq P(X=x\mid Z=z,W=w)$ for all $x,w,z$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is discrete and $Z,W$ are discrete or continuous, I am wondering if it is always the case (or at least non-trivially) that

$$
P(X=x\mid Z=z) \geq P(X=x\mid Z=z,W=w)
$$

for all $x\in X$, $w\in W$, and $z\in Z$?

It appears to make intuitive sense to me because it appears the probability of $X$ given $Z$ and $W$ should be "subsetting" off the probability of $X$ given $Z$. That is, if there is some chance of $X$ given $Z$, then $X$ given $Z$ and $W$ is subdividing the occurrence of $X$ given $Z$ into many more chunks according to $W$, and thus the probability of a chunk occurring should be less than the whole.

In other words, it seems to hold in the finite-sampling perspective, where the above are empirical proportions. However, I am unable to prove this generally. Is there a general result behind this?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X)$ is meaningless when $X$ is a random variable. E.g., if $X$ is the result of a die roll (a number from 1 to 6), $\mathbb{P}(X)$ is "the probability of the result of a die roll" (meaningless). Is $X$ an event? If so, what does it mean for an event to be discrete?

Comment: Are you implying I should fix $X=x$. I have changed the above.

Comment: This seems like the basic idea of conditional probability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) . So in the post you did not mention whether $X, Y, Z$ are independent or not. In the case where the variables are independent, then $Z$ and $W$ contribute no information about $X$, no matter whether any of the variables are discrete or continuous. Perhaps you can clarify the dependency structure you are assuming in the post itself.

Comment: I am assuming that there is no independence existing either marginally nor conditionally among any of the variables. I was hoping for a general result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not true in general (in fact in 'most' cases). For example suppose $W=X$ and $X$ is independent of $Z$. If you take $w=x$ then the inequality becomes $P(X=x)^{2} \geq P(X=x)$ so it is false if $0<P(X=x) <1$.

Answer (score 1):

The claimed relation is not true in general. As a counterexample, suppose $X$ and $W$ are independent and Bernoulli distributed random variables, with each of them taking the values $0$ and $1$ with equal probability. Further, suppose that
\begin{equation}
Z=X+W\quad \text{mod }2.
\end{equation}
Then, it is easy to see that $P(X=0|Z=0,W=0)=1$, whereas $P(X=0|Z=0)=\frac{1}{2}$, and therefore we have $P(X=0|Z=0)\ngeq P(X=0|Z=0,W=0)$.

It seems like you want to capture the fact that "given information about $Z$ and $W$, there is less uncertainty about the value that the random variable $X$ takes, than when given information only about $Z$" (this is true in the example I have mentioned above). This notion of uncertainty reducing upon conditioning more and more random variables is captured very nicely in the subject of [information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) through a quantity known as [Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). Please have a look at this quantity by visiting the link if you have not encountered it before.

So, in the language of information theory, it is true that
\begin{equation}
H(X|Z)\geq H(X|Z,W),
\end{equation}
where $H(X|Z)$ and $H(X|Z,W)$ denote the conditional entropy of $X$ given $Z$ and the conditional entropy of $X$ given $Z$ and $W$. In fact, the above relation between the conditional entropies is a consequence of a more general property: the difference between $H(X|Z)$ and $H(X|Z,W)$ is a quantity in information theory known as [conditional mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information) of $X$ and $W$ given $Z$, which is denoted by $I(X;W|Z)$, and it is a known fact in information theory that  conditional mutual information is always nonnegative.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.